# what the best method for cleaning up url's

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have been looking around the internet for how to clean up my website url's

I want to change from **`clientview.slchandy.co.uk/invoice.php?invoiceno=123456`** to **`clientview.slchandy.co.uk/invoice/123456`**.

I have come across two methods to do it (there most likely more) which is php and `.htaccess` my question which one is the best to use when it comes to speed and reliability?

Thank you very much

Comment: thank you very much is that because it easier to code with or what

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

You're somewhat out of your depth here - while you've obviously asked the question because you don't know the right answer, but your not in a very good position to assess the accuracy/relevance/completeness of any answer you receive here.

But a few pointers:

1) .htaccess has nothing to do with changing URLs. It is an optional extension to the configuration used by some webservers and *may* contain directives to amend the routing of URLs.

2) Using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) with Apache (where you can define mapping rules in .htaccess files) or parsing the requested URL after routing via content negotiation (what you seem to be referring to as "php") are potential solutions are the obvious solutions to the problem.

3) This does not address the problem of Content Negotiation - which might use the 404 handler, a generic Apache handler, a Apache FallbackResource directive or other approach.

The method you choose to implement a solution should be the method which you understand and can fix when it breaks.

The difference in speed is small between these 2 approaches is probably too small to measure. (but enabling support for .htaccess has a BIG impact). As to reliability? That's down to you in both cases.

Comment: thank you very much i have to look into it more as you have confused me a bit lol or get someone else to do it for me it is not something that really needs to be done just thought it would look cleaner when sending the link to my clients via email

Answer (score -1):

Try code like this to clean url.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+movie\.php\?name=([^\s&]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ movie/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]+)/?$ movie.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: is there a general way of doing this because i want to be able to clean up all my urls in clientview.slchandy.co.uk not just my invoice.php as i noticed ur putting in movie.php i want my how website to use the same code

Comment: The first 9 and 12th of the 14 lines have nothing to do with the question asked. Using a permanent redirect in the rewrite rule is a VERY BAD IDEA. The pattern in the last line does not match the example in the question even if the hardcoded strings are substituted.